# Select other PID if select result is empty

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I got this TS:

```
markers.input_readonly_b_price = CONTENT
markers.input_readonly_b_price {
        table = tx_pricelist_prices_full
        select {
          pidInList = 27
          orderBy = uid
          selectFields = uid, group_b_1_3
          # possible conditions
           where = ( hidden='0' AND deleted='0')
        } 
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
          #value  
          1 = TEXT
          1.insertData = 1 
          1.data = field:group_b_1_3
          2 = TEXT
          2.value = *
          3 = TEXT
          3.insertData = 1 
          3.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day          
          stdWrap.prioriCalc = 1   
        }
      }
```

I need to change that TypoScript with that condition:

If on page with id 27 - `pid=27` record inside will have status `deleted/hidden` then read data from `pid=20` else (there is one record visible) read data from `pid=27`

On `pid=20` there will be a record (always). On 'pid=27` will be one record but sometime hidden, sometime visible.

Does anyone have an idea how to set this condition?

Comment: Try `override` with the condition `if.empty = 1`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Could you give some examples?